# Gstreamer video on Android (Qt C++)

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator, gstreamer

I try to use Gstreamer on Android via Qt C++.
I already use Gstreamer on these platforms but now I have an issues with the plugins:

```
G_BEGIN_DECLS
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(coreelements);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audioconvert);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(playback);
G_END_DECLS
void MainWindow::play(){
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(coreelements);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(audioconvert);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(playback);

    GstElement *pipeline;
    GError *error = NULL;

    pipeline = gst_parse_launch("playbin uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-368p.ogv", &error);
    if (!pipeline) {
        ui->label->setText("error");
        return;
    }
    if(error != NULL){
        qDebug("GST error: ");
        qDebug(error->message);

    }else{
        qDebug("GST without errors");
    }

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(pipeline), this->ui->playback_widget->winId());
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    ui->label->setText("Playing...");
}
```

After executing of this code I don't get either video in the playback_widget or the audio, but error var is clear(equals NULL) and label set to "Playing...". So, maybe I missed something?

Comment: check with GST_DEBUG=3 or so.. this is env variable

Comment: @otopolsky thanks! Using GST_DEBUG I got this error: `error: No URI handler implemented for "http"`. So, now I link with `-lgstsouphttpsrc` but I don't know which plugins I need to register, so I still get previous error. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you not use pkg-config? the associated plugin is maybe `soup`.. thats displayed in gst-inspect-1.0 souphttpsrc at the beginngin..

Comment: @otopolsky I already link with `-lsoup-2.4`. By the way, I tried to use pkg-config: I set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to "/home/user/Downloads/gstreamer-1.0-android-armv7-1.8.0/lib/pkgconfig", and project to:
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-1.0
But get: Project ERROR: gstreamer-1.0 development package not found.

Comment: can you execute pkg-config utility to check if it gives you proper paths for headers/libs -  `pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer1.0` ? there must be *.pc files where the actual paths are stored..

Comment: @otopolsky thanks for the remark, I checked it and I got a lot of mentions about  `/home/slomo/cerbero/dist/`: `-pthread -I/home/slomo/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/home/slomo/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/home/slomo/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/slomo/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib/glib-2.0/include -L/home/slomo/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl`. I think that is not right, so, I need to fix these .pc manually?

Comment: @otopolsky I tried to change all mentions about `/home/slomo/cerbero/dist/` to my path, but it's not works, so I still have `Project ERROR: gstreamer-1.0 development package not found`. By the way, what exactly does a `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` variable do? How can I load needed codecs and plugins at the runtime?

Comment: it depends how did you changed it, please update your question about what you tried and what happend.. the GST_PLUGIN_PATH variable should point to place where your gstreamer plugins are store (that is for example library libgstcoreelements.so or libgstrtmp.so)  for it it is for example /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/ (I compiled with make install from sources)